# Plotting chart with epoch time x axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code to plot a chart with matplotlib

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib2
import json

req = urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost:17668/retrieval/data/getData.json?        pv=LNLS:ANEL:corrente&donotchunk")
data = json.load(req)
secs = [x['secs'] for x in data[0]['data']]
vals = [x['val'] for x in data[0]['data']]

plt.plot(secs, vals)
plt.show()
```

The secs arrays is epoch time.

What I want is to plot the data in the x axis (secs) as a date (DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To plot date-based data in matplotlib you must convert the data to the correct format.

One way is to first convert your data to [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#) objects, for an epoch timestamp you should use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp).

You must then convert the `datetime` objects to the right format for matplotlib, this can be handled using [`matplotlib.date.date2num`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date).

Alternatively you can use [`matplotlib.dates.epoch2num`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.epoch2num) and skip converting your date to `datetime` objects in the first place (while this will suit your use-case better initially, I would recommend trying to keep date based date in `datetime` objects as much as you can when working, it will save you a headache in the long run).

Once you have your data in the correct format you can plot it using [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date).

Finally to format your x-axis as you wish you can use a [`matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) object to choose how your ticks will look.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate

import numpy as np

# Generate some random data.
N = 40
now = 1398432160
raw = np.array([now + i*1000 for i in range(N)])
vals = np.sin(np.linspace(0,10,N))

# Convert to the correct format for matplotlib.
# mdate.epoch2num converts epoch timestamps to the right format for matplotlib
secs = mdate.epoch2num(raw)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the date using plot_date rather than plot
ax.plot_date(secs, vals)

# Choose your xtick format string
date_fmt = '%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S'

# Use a DateFormatter to set the data to the correct format.
date_formatter = mdate.DateFormatter(date_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_formatter)

# Sets the tick labels diagonal so they fit easier.
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: It gave me the following error: AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'autoftm_xdate'

Comment: You have copied the code in incorrectly then as I have `fig.autofmt_xdate()` not `fig.autoftm_xdate()`.

Comment: Inconsistent use of `matplotlib.dates` and `matplotlib.date`. The correct use is `matplotlib.dates`.

Comment: FYI, `matplotlib.dates.epoch2num` is getting deprecated in an upcoming version of matplotlib (3.3.2 I believe)

Comment: So if that gets deprecated, what is the recommended way?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the ticks locations and formats on your plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import time

secs = [10928389,102928123,383827312,1238248395]
vals = [12,8,4,12]

plt.plot(secs,vals)

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.FixedLocator(secs))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    mtick.FuncFormatter(lambda pos,_: time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(pos)))
    )
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```